# Stream low-latency video to Chrome on Nexus 7

Tags: google-chrome, video-streaming, html5-video, gstreamer, nexus-7

We need to stream live video, with little to no delay, to an Android tablet.  We would vastly prefer to stream to a web application, rather than having to write an Android app.  However, so far, my efforts to stream video to Chrome on a Nexus 7, using gstreamer and a webcam, have proved too laggy, with a delay of something like 5 seconds.  I've been trying to use webm/vp8, but am not set on using that if something else works better.

Perhaps there are options to gstreamer that I'm not using?  Is there a better codec/format/whatever?

```
gst-launch-0.10 -q v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! \
  'video/x-raw-yuv,framerate=30/1,width=320,height=240' ! \
  vp8enc max-latency=1 ! webmmux name='mux' streamable='true' ! fdsink fd=1
```

Is the gstreamer command line I've been using, but gstreamer is not a requirement.  If we have to write our own C code to use some advanced options in webm, for example, that would not be a problem.

Comment: is this issue specific to Android ? or you getting same behavior on vlc or other desktop player as well.

Comment: @rajneesh - it's pretty slow in Chrome on my desktop as well, just that there are more video formats supported on the desktop, so I can likely find one that's reasonably fast.

Comment: We got things "kinda-sorta" working with mjpeg, but... it doesn't seem like the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try the approach from the answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020430/look-for-fastest-video-encoder-with-least-lag-to-stream-webcam-streaming-to-ipad) post.

Following those advices with libxh264 and ffmpeg result in really small latency.